# iPhone UITableView Weirdness

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, uitabbar, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm not even sure what to call this problem. Much less how to search for a solution.

I'm using Xcode 4.
I'm using CoreData.
I have tab bar app. 4 different tabs.
This is an issue from the simulator.

The root table view for two of the tab is populated by an array of controllers.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

SecondViewController *nextController = [self.medControllersArray objectAtIndex:row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

When drilling down to one of the controllers, there's another table table view as you can see.

When tapping the Add button in the next controller's table view and adding a name or whatever to populate the table view, if you go to another next controller's table view it is populated with the same info and the other table view.

Since I was getting the infamous `+entityForName` error

I add this in viewDidLoad

```
 if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
{ 
    managedObjectContext = [(MIT2AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext_: %@",  managedObjectContext);
}
```

Add this in the app's delegate method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (!context) {
    NSLog(@"\nCould not create *context for self");
}

viewController.managedObjectContext = context;
```

I did this for each *next* view controller I had and the *root* views for the two tabs whose root view isn't populated by and array of controllers.

I also get this warning in the console when a next view is pushed:

> ```
> After managedObjectContext_: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x5934e10>
> ```

I hope it all makes sense. And that someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank GOD!!! It's worked out. I made (I'm sure of it) a rookie Core Data mistake in my data model.

I was getting duplicates in the simulator (as well as the phone) because of this mistake:

In the data model I have an entity for medications and all the attributes, blah, blah, blah. I created a class and decided to use just that class to share between 3 table views, current meds, past meds, and allergies. In doing so naturally there was no differentiation. I went back, create a new model, merged yada, yada, and added 3 new entities for the current, past, and allergies. Then set there parent entity to the main med entity and abstracted the parent. When I went through again and reworked the code to the new entities. Everything worked! No more duplications. Well, really, no more triplication.

For the warning I was getting (not error, the app still build, didn't crash and you could still work through it) was do to the managed object context. To silence the infamous +entityForName error I tried something that I either saw in a book or from Apple. I imported the AppDelegate to each of my tables and in fetchedResultsController did this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
MIT2AppDelegate *mit = [[MIT2AppDelegate alloc] init];

if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
    //if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    //  the entity name
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Allergies" inManagedObjectContext:mit.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

While reworking the code I tried what tomasBULL recommended:
[How can I solve NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: fail report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850601/how-can-i-solve-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-entityforname-fail)

That's where the error was coming from. So I went back to what I had before and now, no more error.

I do this in my AppDelegate managedObjectModel

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel{
    if (managedObjectModel != nil){
        return managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"MIT2ver 3" ofType:@"mom" inDirectory:@"MIT2ver2.momd"];

        NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];

    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

Because before I had made another rookie mistake of when I added a model I took out the space. Thanks to udibr answer: [Implementation of “Automatic Lightweight Migration” for Core Data (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310216/implementation-of-automatic-lightweight-migration-for-core-data-iphone)

Thanks to everyone who answered. GOD worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to remove the app from the simulator? sometimes when you change something on the core data structure the app crashes at it fails to find the data correctly. Removing the app will force it to rebuild the database.

Comment: Not sometimes , when you use a core data model and change it the app will crash unless u take the appropriate steps to migrate the core data model...when u delete the application the previous core data model is lost along with all the data so if it's actually a second version of an application the core dat model should be migrated...